# Given a string, does "xyz" appear in the middle of the string?

Tags: java

> Given a string, does "xyz" appear in the middle of the string? To
>   define middle, we'll say that the number of chars to the left and
>   right of the "xyz" must differ by at most one. This problem is harder
>   than it looks.

My solution works without the second last line except for one condition: if str="xyx"
Is it possible to modify the for loop to take this into account...I'm struggling with understanding why it doesn't.

My solution does work I'm just trying to get a better understanding of what I'm doing. I know I could add it into the first if statement but I want to know why it doesn't work without it.

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  for (int i=0;i<str.length()-3;i++) {
    if (str.substring(i,i+3).equals("xyz")) {
      String front =str.substring(0,i);
      String end = str.substring(i+3);
      int a =Math.abs(front.length() -end.length());
      if (a<=1) return true;
    }    
  }
  if (str.equals("xyz")) return true;
  return false;
```

Comment: What is the question? And what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Ok, now you've incorporated a question. Now my question is, why are you using a loop? You already know where to look in the string.

Comment: The coding bat section the question is from Is about using loops...so thats why I automatically did...

Comment: I think they want you to use a loop for checking the characters instead of substring, not to find the location of the substring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think i remember this question - it's [this question from Codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p159772), I believe. Excellent web site, learned a lot from that site back when I started programming. There's absolutely no reason to use a loop, though.

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  boolean result = false; 
  int i = str.length()/2 -1;

  if (str.length() >= 3 && (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("xyz") || (str.length()%2 == 0 && str.substring(i-1, i+2).equals("xyz"))  )) {
      result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

So, let's walk through this and why it works. Firstly, `str.length() >= 3`, because if the string isn't at least as long as "xyz", there's no way it can contain "xyz".

There are two main cases to this problem, we need to think of. The string can have an even or an uneven length. In the uneven case, it's easy:

**The Uneven case**

```
AAAxyzAAA // length = 9
012345678 // the indexes
    ^     // that's the middle, which can be calculated by length/2
          // (since this is an integer divison, we disregard whatever comes after the decimal point)
```

So to get the start of the `xyz`-substring, we simply subtract one from this number - which is exactly what `i` is doing:

```
AAAxyzAAA // length = 9
012345678 // the indexes
   i      // i = length/2-1 = 3
```

So if `str.substring(i, i+3)` is `xyz`, we can return true!

**The Even Case**
Now, this can be a bit more tricky, since there is no true "middle" of the string. In fact, two indexes could be called the middle, so we have two sub-cases:

```
AAAAAAAA // length = 8
01234567 // the indexes
   ^^    // Which one is the true middle character?
```

In fact, the middle would be between index 3 and 4. However, we are performing integer divisions, length/2 is always the largest (rightmost) of the two possible "middles". And since we calculate `i` using the middle, the same as in the uneven case applies - `str.substring(i, i+3)` could be considered the middle part of the string.

```
AAAxyzAA 
01234567 
   ^^^     // str.substring(i, i+3)
   i
```

But suppose our string was `AAxyzAAA` - that could *also* be considered the middle part of the string. So we need to move our substring check "to the left" - so we subtract 1 from it.

```
AAxyzAAA 
01234567 
  ^^^      // str.substring(i-1, i+2)
   i       // i is still at "the old" location
```

**So is it even or not?**

To check whether the string is even or uneven, we use the **modulo** operator, `%`. The easiest way to think of what it does is "what would be left over after i divided with this number?". So `3 % 2` would be 1. In our case, we want to make sure that the number is divisible by 2 with nothing left over - because that means it was an even number. Therefore, we need to check whether `str.length() % 2 == 0` before we make our "move-to-the-left" check. If not, we could risk going out of bounds on the string. If the string was 3 characters long, and we moved one to the left... we would check the substring starting at index -1, and that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Put it all together, and there you go!

Comment: The part str.length()%2==0 - hows does that tell you it is in the middle?

Comment: @JerryMurphy It gives whether the string is of an even length. Although he should really surround the last conditions with brackets.

Comment: I've expanded upon and explained the solution - it's quite thorough, so sorry about the wall of text.

Comment: That has explained everything perfectly! It's incredible to speed and quality of the answers here..Thanks for your help Tobias

Comment: I've updated the code with @ZongZhengLi's suggestion. It does improve greatly on the clarity for the reader. Note that there's no actual difference between surrounding the conditions after `||` with brackets or not in this case due to operator precedence - the `||` will be considered *after* the `&&`-operator. When there is more than one logical operator in a statement (and they are not explicitly grouped using parentheses) `!` will be evaluated first, then `&&`, and finally `||`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say something as simple as:

```
public void test() {
  test("Hello", "ll");
  test("Hello", "He");
  test("Hello", "el");
  test("Hello", "lo");
  test("Hello", "Hell");
  test("Hello", "ello");
  test("Hello", "Hello");
  test("Hell", "He");
  test("Hell", "el");
  test("Hell", "ll");
}

private void test(String s, String p) {
  System.out.println(p + (inMiddle(s, p) ? " in " : " not in ") + s);
}

// Is the pattern in the middle of the string.
public static boolean inMiddle(String s, String p) {
  int d = s.length() - p.length();
  return at(s, p, d / 2) || ((d & 1) == 1 && at(s, p, (d / 2) + 1));
}

private static boolean at(String s, String p, int i) {
  return i >= 0 && i < s.length() && s.substring(i).startsWith(p);
}
```

Results look correct to me:

```
ll in Hello
He not in Hello
el in Hello
lo not in Hello
Hell in Hello
ello in Hello
Hello in Hello
He not in Hell
el in Hell
ll not in Hell
```

I have confirmed that this matches Tobias' solution exactly when `p` = "xyz".

Comment: @JerryMurphy It's about the algorithm, not the name of the method. Also this is the general solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks OldCurmudgeon and Zong Zheng Li

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  int len = str.length();
  if (len < 3){ return false; }
  int even = (len+1)%2;
  int mid = len/2;
  return str.substring(mid-1-even, mid+2).contains("xyz");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I could come up with:

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
    str = "  " + str + "  ";
    int even = (str.length()+1)%2;
    int mid = (str.length())/2;
    str = str.substring(mid-1-even, mid+2);
    return str.contains("xyz");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {

   int len = str.length();
   if(len < 3) {return false;}
   if(len==3 && str.equals("xyz")) {return true;}

    int index = middleIndex(str);

   String left = str.substring(0,index) ;
   String right= str.substring(index+3) ; 

  //Return based on the difference by at most 1
  return (Math.abs(left.length()-right.length()) <=1);
}

public int middleIndex(String str) {

   int middleLen  = (str.length())/2;
   int index= 0;

   //Find an index that could be in the middle of the string with 
   // "xyz" 
   for(int i=middleLen-2; i < middleLen; i++ ) {
      if(str.substring(i, i+3).equals("xyz") ) {
       index= i;
     }
   }
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  if (str.length() >= 3)
  {
    // if odd
    if (str.length() % 2 == 1)
    {
      //axyzb
      //01234
      //length = 5; 5 is odd.
      //length / 2 = 2;
      //2 minus 1 = 1
      //1 is where xyz starts

      //aaxyzbb
      //0123456
      //length = 7; 7 is odd.
      //length / 2 = 3;
      //3 minus 1 = 2
      //2 is where xyz starts.

      //....

      //This pattern works with all odd numbers.
      if (str.substring((str.length() / 2) - 1, ((str.length() / 2) - 1) + 3).equals("xyz"))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    //if even
    else
    {


      //for evens that occur with a larger amount before "xyz" than after

      //axyz
      //0123
      //length = 4; 4 is even;
      //4 - 1 = 3;
      //3 / 2 = 1
      //1 is where xyz starts.

      //aaxyzb
      //012345
      //length = 6; 6 is even;
      //6 - 1 = 5;
      //5 / 2 = 2
      //2 is where xyz starts.

      //...

      //This pattern works for all even numbers where there is a larger amount of characters before the xyz.

      if (str.substring((str.length() - 1) / 2, ((str.length() - 1) / 2) + 3).equals("xyz"))
      {
        return true;
      }

      //For the cases where there are more characters after "xyz" than before.

      //xyzb
      //0123
      //length = 4; 4 is even;
      //4 - 1 = 3;
      //3 / 2 = 1
      //1 - 1 = 0;
      //xyz starts at 0;

      //axyzbb
      //012345
      //length = 6; 6 is even;
      //6 - 1 = 5;
      //5 / 2 = 3;
      //2 - 1 = 1;
      //xyz starts at 1;

      //...

      //The pattern continues onwards for all cases where there are more characters after xyz than before.

      else if (str.substring((((str.length() - 1) / 2) - 1), (((str.length() - 1) / 2) -1) + 3).equals("xyz"))
      {
        return true;
      }

      //If there is no instance of xyz in these areas.
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  // If our string is less than 3 in length.
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: No loops, just math.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {

  return str.length()>2 && str.length()%2==1 && str.substring((str.length()-1)/2-1,(str.length()/2+1)+1).contains("xyz") || str.length()>2 && str.length()%2==0 && (str.substring(str.length()/2-2,str.length()/2+1).contains("xyz") || str.substring(str.length()/2-1,str.length()/2+2).contains("xyz"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  int index = str.indexOf("x");
  if(index < 0)
    return false;
  while(index >=0 && (index+3 <= str.length()) ){
    if(str.substring(index,index+3).equals("xyz") && Math.abs(str.substring(0,index).length() - str.substring(index+3).length()) <=1)
    return true;
    index = str.indexOf("x",index+1);
  }
  return false;
}
```